# Reliable .NET API for Elastic Search

Tags: .net, api, elasticsearch

I am going to implement Elastic Search for my website which is .NET based. I have decided to use Elastic Search for the search solution. I am looking for advice on what would the best approach to feed data to index and then read that data would be? The data read and write is all JSON based.

I have looked at some open source clients but I am not convinced of their reliability. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing my own little library for this. The libraries are still not reliable and are a work in progress.

Comment: Any luck in the last 6 months finding a library?